# Change image dynamically into a ListView from JSON

Tags: android, json, listview, imageview

I have the following code retrivieng data from URL in JSON format and updating a ListView. The code is working perfectly. In the xml layout, i have two TextView and one ImageView.

How can I update the ImageView dinamically?

I'm not getting the images from a URL, my images are stored inside my project  (res/drawable folder). The var TAG_ICON has the name of my image which is exact the same name of the image inside my project.

Example:

response from JSON: TAG_ICON = lamp01

name of the image: lamp01.png

This is my main Class:

```
public class DeviceList extends ListActivity  {

        private static String url = "http://192.168.10.2/myhome/get_all_devices.php";

        // Hashmap ListView
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> deviceList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // class JSON
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // Criar JSON Nodes
        private static final String TAG_DEVICES = "devices";
        private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
        private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
        private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";
        private static final String TAG_ICON = "icon";

        // array JSONArray
        JSONArray devices = null;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.device_list);

            // Loat ListView
            new LoadDevices().execute();
            ListView lv = getListView();
        }

        // class LoadDevices
        class LoadDevices extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
            @Override       
            protected void onPreExecute(){          
                super.onPreExecute();                   
            }

            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {   

                // JSON string from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

                try {
                // add to array
                devices = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DEVICES);

                // Looping trough all results
                for(int i = 0; i < devices.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = devices.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String description = c.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);
                    String icon = c.getString(TAG_ICON);


                    // creating a HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();     

                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);                    
                    map.put(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description);
                    map.put(TAG_ICON, icon);


                    deviceList.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url){      

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {              
                    public void run() {
                        // update JSON ListView

                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(DeviceList.this, deviceList,R.layout.device_row,
                                new String[]{
                                    TAG_NAME,
                                    TAG_DESCRIPTION,
                                }, 
                                new int[] {
                                    R.id.device_row_TextViewName,
                                    R.id.device_row_TextViewDescription,
                                });

                        // update listView


                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                });
            }
        }   

    }
```

Here's my XML layout for a single row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/device_row_RelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/device_row_LinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:padding="3dip" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/device_row_ImageViewIcon"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:layout_width="60dip"
            android:layout_height="60dip"
            android:src="@drawable/lamp03" />
    </LinearLayout>



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/device_row_TextViewName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/device_row_RelativeLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="75dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/device_row_ImageViewIcon"
        android:text="Lâmpada do Quarto"
        android:textColor="#4169E1"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/device_row_TextViewDescription"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/device_row_TextViewName"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/device_row_TextViewName"
        android:paddingTop="1dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Usado para controlar a lâmpada do quarto."
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="13dip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the images are in your drawable folder you need to first use the title to find the image in your drawable folder. Make sure that the title of the file is the same as the title tag you are returning from the server.

```
int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier("yourpackagename:drawable/" + TAG_TITLE, null, null);
```

Then just find the ImageView and set the image

```
ImageView picture = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.device_row_ImageViewIcon);
picture.setImageResource(imageId);
```